# Xamarin.Auth and web api tokens

Tags: asp.net-web-api, xamarin, bearer-token, xamarin.auth

I'm making calls to a Web API using a xamarin mobile app and I was wondering when receiving my authorization bearer token could I not simply store it in the xamarin.auth account store along with the user's credentials?  I figured this would be a  better place than say a global variable in the app. Looking for feedback and any better options.  Thanks!

Comment: Use Settings plugin to store : https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/SettingsPlugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion there is nothing wrong with using the account store for storing an access token (using the account properties dictionary). I did it myself on one app where I didn't have any other data to persist, so didn't have a custom data access layer.

Answer (score 0):

Access tokens should not be stored. Refresh tokens are OK, but Access not.
From security point of view.